# llamar a función ajax al presionar tecla enter

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un problema con una función javascript, resulta que en mi pagina tengo un text y un botón, al presionar el botón se ejecuta la función javascript la que envía datos de un formulario a un controlador de laravel, esto funciona sin problemas , pero necesito que también se ejecute la función si el usuario presiona la tecla enter cuando esta en el text, no se como hacerlo ya que si ahora lo presiono me da un error indicando que envié valores vacíos a la función.

esta es mi función

```js
function temporal(ruta)
{
   const codigobarra=$('#Txt_serie').val();
   const sku_ext=$('#Txt_codigo').val();
   const Idservicio=$('#Txt_servicio').val(); 
   const Numguia=$('#Txt_numguia').val(); 
   const Idmaterial=$('#Txt_idmaterial').val();
   const Idproveedor=$('#Txt_prov').val();
   const Numcantidad=$('#Txt_cant').val();
   const identificador=$('#Txt_identificador').val();
   const Numfila=$('#Txt_fila').val();
   const usuario=$('#Txt_user').val();
   const estado=1;
    
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:ruta, 
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                _token:$('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                temp_mat_id:Idmaterial,
                tem_mst_id:estado,
                temp_ser_id:Idservicio,
                temp_serie:codigobarra,
                temp_guia:Numguia,
                temp_pro_id:Idproveedor,
                temp_identificador:identificador,
                temp_nwa_id:1,
                temp_use_id:usuario
            },
            success:function () {
                           document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML=`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">OK</div>`
                  document.getElementById('Txt_serie').value= "";
                  $('#Txt_serie').focus(); 
                }
               
         });
        
         return false;
         
    
}
```

```html
  {{-- este el text que no logro que me funcione al presionar enter --}}

<input type="text" name="Txt_serie" id='Txt_serie' placeholder="0"  class="form-control">

 {{-- este el tbotón que llama a la función--}}

<button name="Btn_agregar" id="Btn_agregar" type="button" onclick="temporal('{{ route('guiaingresos.insert') }}')"   class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button>
```

espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function temporal(ruta)
{
   const codigobarra=$('#Txt_serie').val();
   const sku_ext=$('#Txt_codigo').val();
   const Idservicio=$('#Txt_servicio').val(); 
   const Numguia=$('#Txt_numguia').val(); 
   const Idmaterial=$('#Txt_idmaterial').val();
   const Idproveedor=$('#Txt_prov').val();
   const Numcantidad=$('#Txt_cant').val();
   const identificador=$('#Txt_identificador').val();
   const Numfila=$('#Txt_fila').val();
   const usuario=$('#Txt_user').val();
   const estado=1;
    
    document.getElementById("Btn_agregar"),addEventListener("click", ()=>{
       $.ajax(
        {
            url:ruta, 
            type:'POST',
            data: {
                _token:$('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                temp_mat_id:Idmaterial,
                tem_mst_id:estado,
                temp_ser_id:Idservicio,
                temp_serie:codigobarra,
                temp_guia:Numguia,
                temp_pro_id:Idproveedor,
                temp_identificador:identificador,
                temp_nwa_id:1,
                temp_use_id:usuario
            },
            success:function () {
                           document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML=`<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">OK</div>`
                  document.getElementById('Txt_serie').value= "";
                  $('#Txt_serie').focus(); 
                }
               
         });

     })
        
         return false;
         
    
}
```

```html
  {{-- este el text que no logro que me funcione al presionar enter --}}

<input type="text" name="Txt_serie" id='Txt_serie' placeholder="0"  class="form-control">

 {{-- este el tbotón que llama a la función--}}

<button name="Btn_agregar" id="Btn_agregar" type="button" onclick="temporal('{{ route('guiaingresos.insert') }}')"   class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button>
```

simplemente obtienes una refecencia al elemente con el id `Btn_agregar` y luego escuchas el click y dentro de la funcion agregas la peticon ajax, si quieres que toda la funcion `temporal()` se ejecute cuando se haga click al boton, entonces haces algo como esto...

```
document.getElementById("Btn_agregar"),addEventListener("click", temporal())
```

esta porcion de codigo la agregas fuera de la funcion `temporal()` entonces cuando hagas click en el boton se ejecutara toda la funcion `temporal()`, espero que haya entendido bien tu problema y que con esto te pueda ayudar.

para poder ejecutar dicha función mediante un `enter`, deberías usar un formulario,algo como esto

```
<form id="submit">
  <input type="text" name="Txt_serie" id='Txt_serie' placeholder="0"  
  class="form-control">

  <button name="Btn_agregar" id="Btn_agregar" type="submit" 
  onclick="temporal('{{ route('guiaingresos.insert') }}')"   class="btn btn- 
  info">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

y deberias modificar la funcion asi

```
document.getElementById("submit"),addEventListener("submit", temporal())
```

de esta forma aprevecharias el uso de `enter` para poder ejecutar tu funcion `temporal()`

Comment: Hola @Enzo gracias por responder, el codigo que pusiste es para que se ejecute con el botón, pero no me funciona al presionar la tecla Enter

Comment: ahora lo arreglo

Comment: Excelente @Enzo !!! muchas gracias